# Creating loading display in PySide with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside, python-multithreading

I am trying to display a loading graphic(for now just a label) at the beginning of my pyside program while another function is running. After it's done it should continue and load the main GUI. I have this so far

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui

class DoStuff:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ReturnInformation(self):
        time.sleep(20)                              #Sleep to simulate processing time
        return "information"

class Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.initQ = queue.Queue()
        self.initthread = threading.Thread(target=self.InitThread)
        self.initthread.daemon = True
        self.initthread.start()

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.BlankCursor)

        self.loaddisplay = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.loaddisplay.move(20, 20)
        self.loaddisplay.setText("Loading...")
        self.show()

        self.initthread.join()
        self.MainDisplay()
        self.show()

    def InitThread(self):
        self.dostuff = DoStuff()


    def MainDisplay(self):
        self.display = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.display.setStyleSheet("font: 70pt Helvetica; color: white;")
        self.display.move(20, 20)
        self.display.setText(self.dostuff.ReturnInformation())

        self.manager = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.manager.timeout.connect(self.Update)
        self.manager.start(100000)

    def Update(self):                                                  #Update the information once in a while
        self.timedisplay.setText(self.dostuff.ReturnInformation())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that only the load graphic is displayed and the GUI from `MainDisplay()` is never displayed. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with how I'm calling the `show()`function. Is that the problem, and how do I fix it?

Also, how would I delete the loading label once it has finished loading?

P.S. (I asked this question before, but it got no answers or comments and low views so I deleted it and am asking the question again)

Comment: You must show the implementation of InitThread and MainDisplay if you want us to help you or you should provide an MVCE.

Comment: what is Time, Weather, News; you understand what verifiable means.

Comment: This type of problem requires that you provide a code that can be replicated, if it is not likely to be answered, if you share your project via github or similar, you can help or at least share a code that can be executed.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok I've changed it so that it should be replicable like you said.

Comment: Now it is much better, I already have a possible solution but because it calls Update if ReturnInformation () always returns a unique value. Or maybe ReturnInformation () depends on some other task? Please model that part better.

Comment: My question about `ReturnInformation()` is: what if it also consumes time like `__init__`?

Comment: Ok I changed it to answer your question and better represent my actual code.

Comment: Does my solution work?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to work on it yesterday I will do it today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although python provides several ways to execute task through threads these do not necessarily conform to the rules of Qt, it is appropriate to use the tools of the framework such as QThread:

```
class DoStuffThread(QtCore.QThread):
    displaySignal = QtCore.Signal(str)
    timeSignal = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.moveToThread(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimeout)
        self.stuff = DoStuff()

    def onTimeout(self):
        data = self.stuff.ReturnInformation()
        self.timeSignal.emit(data)

    def run(self):
        data = self.stuff.ReturnInformation()
        self.displaySignal.emit(data)
        self.timer.start(20000)
        loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
        loop.exec_()


class DoStuff:
    def ReturnInformation(self):
        time.sleep(2)  # Sleep to simulate processing time
        return "information-{}".format(QtCore.QTime.currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss"))


class Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.BlankCursor)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())

        self.loaddisplay = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.display = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.timedisplay = QtGui.QLabel(self)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.loaddisplay)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.display)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.timedisplay)

        self.thread = DoStuffThread(self)
        self.thread.displaySignal.connect(self.display.setText, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.thread.timeSignal.connect(self.timedisplay.setText, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.thread.start()

        self.loaddisplay.move(20, 20)
        self.loaddisplay.setText("Loading...")
        self.display.setStyleSheet("font: 70pt Helvetica; color: white;")
        self.display.move(20, 20)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.thread.quit()
        QtGui.QWidget.closeEvent(self, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Main()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When I ran your code I got an error in 'run()'. It says 'DoStuffThread object has no attribute "stuff"'. I can see that 'stuff' is clearly defined in 'onTimeout' so I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: @Sebiancoder I had made a modification without testing it, but I corrected it, check it back please.